# Redirect all referral links with Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to make a secure download page. In an effort to deter that person from simply copying the URL and sharing it with the world, I'd like to use Javascript to redirect any referral that comes from outside of my domain.

Here's what I'm trying, but with no luck.

```
    var referrer = /^(https?:\/\/[^\/]*)/.exec(document.referrer)
if (referrer && referrer[-1] == "http://mydomain.com") {
    ducument.location = "http://mydomain.com/accessdenied"
}
```

Comment: Your use of the word `secure` is a problem here.  `document.referrer` can be spoofed to anything one wants so it is in no way `secure` and enforcement on the client side is NEVER secure.  If you want secure, you probably want to look more in the direction of a limited use URL that could be combined with a paired cookie or security code.

Comment: To be more secure that the js check, you have to do this check on the server-side, e.g. in PHP or whatever language you are using. But this does not work if the user fakes the referrer header.

Comment: like jfriend00 said, the javascript part is not secure. Simply put an identifier on that user session works better for these cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typos. Everyone has also convinced me to go about this with a better solution. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it from your server side, some one will disable javascript and get what he want :D

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this on the server.  Not sure what server side your using but no matter which one you can get access to the server properties $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Answer (score 0):

typo,and "http" may not be used to test

```
var referrer = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]*)/.exec(document.referrer)
if (referrer && referrer[1] == "mydomain.com") {
    document.location = "http://mydomain.com/accessdenied"
}
```